# Clear object variables

Tags: c#

This is my class Designation.

```
class Designation
{
    private string strDesigNo;
    private string strDesigName;
    private string strDesigDesc;

    public string DesigNo
    {
        set { strDesigNo = value; }
        get { return strDesigNo; }
    }
    public string DesigName
    {
        set { strDesigName = value; }
        get { return strDesigName; }
    }
    public string DesigDesc
    {
        set { strDesigDesc = value; }
        get { return strDesigDesc; }
    }
}
```

In my user interface form  on click of Save button I assign the values to  my Department class  and then send it to save method in another class as follows.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesignationNumber.Text.Trim().ToString())) 
    { 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesignationName.Text.Trim().ToString())) 
        {         
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesignationtDescription.Text.Trim().ToString())) 
            {
                objDesignation.DesigNo = txtDesignationNumber.Text.Trim().ToString();
                objDesignation.DesigName = txtDesignationName.Text.Trim().ToString();
                objDesignation.DesigDesc=txtDesignationtDescription.Text.Trim().ToString(); 

                objDesignationBLL.insertDesignation(objDesignation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// What I need is immediately after sending the object values to insertDesignation method,clear all the values.

//That means I need it as follows.

```
objDesignation.DesigNo ='';

objDesignation.DesigName = '';

objDesignation.DesigDesc = '';
```

Is there a good practice to empty these object variable values to null without disposing the object or without setting the object to null?

Comment: you are not setting it to null....you are assigning empty string..Generally you will Dispose objDesignation not its individual property....Dispose of objDesignation should handle any internal reference which needs to be freed.....

Comment: I would remove those `Desig` prefixes and just have the full name of the property, so it describes exactly what data the property is supposed to hold

Comment: While you can certainly write Java or Pascal in any language, it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with the recommended practices and code-style conventions of the language you are actually using.

Comment: `Text.Trim()` returns a string, so using `Text.Trim().ToString()` is unneccessary.

Comment: In most languages, it's a bad idea to reuse the same structure/class instance to store completely different data. You gain nothing while you end up with more complex, less efficient code.

Comment: Thanks all for replies.

Dear  Panagiotis Kanavos

I m not trying to use the same class to store different data.Here in my case I have to save several Designations into the databse.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to reset your variable, you could just assign a new instance:

```
objDesignation = new Designation();
```

Comment: It works.But assigning new Instance many number of times....will it give a memory bulk? or is safe ? Please explain

Comment: Your object is a few bytes big. And if it runs out of scope, the garbage collector comes in and frees the memory. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I suggest using *local variable* for the local task

```
  Designation objDesignation = new ...

  // Let's avoid arrow head antipattern:
  // if any of Text is significant (i.e. has non-whitespace items)  
  // then insert a designation 
  if (new [] {
        txtDesignationNumber.Text, 
        txtDesignationName.Text, 
        txtDesignationtDescription.Text}
      .Any(c => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c)) {

    // create and insert a Designation;
    // there's no need to expose dsgn to the outer scope
    var dsgn = new Designation() {
      DesigNo = txtDesignationNumber.Text.Trim(),
      DesigName = txtDesignationName.Text.Trim(),
      DesigDesc = txtDesignationtDescription.Text.Trim()
    };

    objDesignationBLL.insertDesignation(dsgn);
  }

  // objDesignation hasn´t been changed
  objDesignation...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would re-structure that class:

```
class Designation
{
    public string Number { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Description { get;set; }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Number = string.Empty;
        this.Name = string.Empty;
        this.Description = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I've added the method `Clear()` which should reset the properties when called:

`objDesignation.Clear()`

I personally would just new up a instance of the `Designation` again:

`objDesignation = new Designation()`

once you are done with the data.

---

As an aside, I would advise you make your variable names as explicit as possible. Just so it is easier in the long run to remember what was going on.

Comment: Think of this scenario.

My  DesigDesc variable is null.So its not mandatory.
I save the first record as follows.

objDesignation.DesigNo ='001';
 objDesignation.DesigName ='Store Excecutive' ;                objDesignation.DesigDesc='Incharge of the stores';

Now I save this and come to next record where I dont have a DesigDesc.

Now the issue is when inserting this it grabs the value of the last record.

I know this should be avoided while validating my parameters.But other than that is there a solution?(Creating new instance solves my issue OK.)Any comments

Comment: You should put that in your original question. I'm unsure what your issue is, it seems to me like you have a bigger design problem and should ask that as a new question.